# How to send multiple identical HTTP POST message instantly

Tags: apache, http

I have people cheating in my game by sending multiple HTTP POST message the game server (php + apache) to gain items. I have fixed that loophole but I want to test if my fix was correct.

I have tried some of the chrome plugin to send POST messages but I cant imitate sending them in the same instant, for example 5 identical POST message all send out less that 100ms to the same IP in between them.

I have a Centos and a windows machine, would appreciate any script or program recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Python installed (your CentOS machine would), the following will do what you're after using only built-ins. You'll just need to tweak the `conn.request` line to pass in any body or headers your server requires.

```
from threading import Thread
import httplib, sys

REQUESTS = 5

def doRequest():
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.google.com")   
    conn.request("POST", '/some/url')

for i in range(REQUESTS):
    t = Thread(target=doRequest)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
```

Comment: Thanks, it is quick and easy!